# Array of buttons in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, button, kotlin

How can I create array of buttons in android studio in Kotlin? I've created buttons with their ids in a xml file, now I want to use the same buttons in my Kotlin code as array's elements.

I've tried something like this:

```
var buttons: Array<Button> = Array(25)
```

and then:

```
buttons[0] = btn1 // btn1 as the id from xml file
```

However button names from xml don't work in kotlin file, how can I use them?

Comment: `arrayOfNulls(25)` + `buttons[i]?.let { ... }` / `arrayOf(btn1, btn2, btn3)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize an array in classes in kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55196835/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-classes-in-kotlin)

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi Why? I'm not OP.

Comment: @Zoe of course sorry :)

Answer (score 4):

Supposed you have a layout like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:visibility="visible"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button android:id="@+id/btOne" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="one"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btTwo" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="two"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btThree" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="three"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

First, apply kotlin extensions plugin for syntetic syntax in your `build.gradle` with

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Then, you can simply initalize an array of buttons in your code by doing:

```
val buttons = arrayOf(btOne, btTwo, btThree)
```

Otherwise, if you don't want to use kotlin syntetic, simply use the old findviewbyid syntax

```kotlin
val buttons = arrayOf(
            findViewById(R.id.btOne),
            findViewById(R.id.btTwo),
            findViewById<Button>(R.id.btThree)
        )
```