# How do I initialize an array of buttons in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, button

I want to directly initialize an array of buttons without having to specify variable names. I thought I found the answear here: [Array of buttons in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301944/array-of-buttons-in-kotlin), but the answer throws a NullPointerException. I have also searched google for 'array of buttons in kotlin' but the only relevant info I found was from the question I linked.

I used

```
val intervalButtons = arrayOf(
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.set30secButton),
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.set60secButton),
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.set90secButton),
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.set120secButton)
    )
```

However I also tried to apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' in the build.gradle file and just using

```
val intervalButtons = arrayOf(set30secButton, set60secButton, set90secButton, set120secButton)
```

but this still throws a NullPointerException.

If I use

```
        btn1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.set30secButton)
```

it works like a charm, but like I said, I don't want to have to specify every variable name if I don't have to.

Comment: Yes, it would throw null pointer if you declared the array at class level, do it locally or use `lateinit` or `lazy`, you should init after the view inflated, in activity after `setContentView` and in fragment in `onViewCreated`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be putting the code in the wrong place. You didn't specify that, but it's either in the class itself (in which case `findViewById` would most likely return null) or in `onCreate` - in which case it would not be visible outside this function

Either way, the correct way either be:

```
...
private lateinit var intervalButtons: Array<Button>
...
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setContentView(R.layout.your_view) // <- this is important, must be before     findViewById
    intervalButtons = arrayOf(
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.set30secButton),
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.set60secButton),
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.set90secButton),
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.set120secButton)
    )
    ...
}
```

`lateinit var` means that the variable will be initialized later and as such doesn't need to be initialized at once

Or like such:

```
val intervalButtons: Array<Button> by lazy {
    arrayOf(
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.set30secButton),
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.set60secButton),
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.set90secButton),
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.set120secButton)
    )
}
...
override fun onCreate...
```

Here `by lazy` means the variable `intervalButtons` will only be initialized when it's needed - so like when you'd tried to access one of the buttons. In both solutions `findViewById` is called **after** `setContentView`, which might be the issue in your case.

Comment: Yes, I placed the code at the start of the class. Placing it in the onCreate function solved it, thanks!